# How to find MLE for multinomial distribution and Expectation of X1 and X2

Tags: maximum-likelihood, estimators, multinomial-dirichlet-distribution

There are 3 types of flowers that can grow from planting a seed. 
$$P(\text{Daisy}) = \theta_1$$
$$P(\text{Rose}) = (1-\theta_1)\theta_2$$
$$P(\text{Sunflower}) = (1-\theta_1)(1-\theta_2)$$

The total number of flowers at the end is $n.$ If $X=(X_1, X_2, X_3)$ is the number of daisies, roses and sunflowers respectively, find the MLEs for $\theta_1$ & $\theta_2$ and $E[X_1]$ and $E[X_2]$ in term of the parameters $\theta_1$ & $\theta_2$.

I am aware that this is a multinomial distribution but I don't know how to go about finding the estimators for the parameters since there are 2 of them.

Comment: Are you able to write down the likelihood for a sample $X=\left(X_1, X_2, X_3\right)$ with $n=X_1+X_2+X_3$?

Comment: @assumednormal no:( I don't know how to do that

Comment: If this is self study, I would recommend adding the self study tag, and then reading the guidelines about submitting those types of questions.

Answer (score 0):

If we're given that $X=\left(X_1,X_2,X_3\right)$ follows a multinomial distribution with parameters $\theta=\left(\theta_1,\left(1-\theta_1\right)\theta_2,\left(1-\theta_1\right)\left(1-\theta_2\right)\right)$, then the likelihood is

\begin{align*}
L\left(X; \theta\right) &\propto \theta_1^{X_1}\left(1-\theta_1\right)^{X_2}\theta_2^{X_2}\left(1-\theta_1\right)^{X_3}\left(1-\theta_2\right)^{X_3}\\
\end{align*}

The log-likelihood is then

\begin{align*}
\ell\left(X; \theta\right) &\approx X_1\log\left(\theta_1\right)+\left(X_2+X_3\right)\log\left(1-\theta_1\right)+X_2\log\left(\theta_2\right)+X_3\log\left(1-\theta_2\right)\\
\end{align*}

Taking derivatives gives

\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial \ell}{\partial \theta_1} &= \frac{X_1}{\theta_1}-\frac{X_2+X_3}{1-\theta_1}\\
\frac{\partial \ell}{\partial \theta_2} &= \frac{X_2}{\theta_2}-\frac{X_3}{1-\theta_2}\\
\end{align*}

Setting the derivatives to 0 and solving gives

\begin{align*}
\hat{\theta}_1 &= \frac{X_1}{X_1+X_2+X_3}\\
\hat{\theta}_2 &= \frac{X_2}{X_2+X_3}\\
\end{align*}